# How can I convert screenshot capture into FEN to analyse on Windows 10+?

Tags: analysis, software, fen

I want to analyze position presented on meeting, web page or video but problem is that I have not FEN to start such analysis. It need manual work to do it.

I want to capture screenshot than convert it into FEN. How can I do it on Windows 10+? (not create image/scan than process it with external tools which is not doing screenshots - I know how to do it in such way.)

On Windows I can use Shift+Window+S to capture region than save to image or to clipboard. Is anybody using some software or tool to do it?

I can write such software with use deep learning but it takes time and maybe it is not need to invent wheel again.

Comment: Who is marked this as duplicate? - This question is not related to any scans but screenshot to FEN. This is not answer - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14601/how-can-i-scan-a-chessboard-and-obtain-its-fen

I do not want to process image with external tool (especially online) but get FEN at once from screenshot!

Comment: But the answers in both questions are the same, so how can the Qs be different!?

Comment: I fear there is no such application that does it directly from a screenshot. We're in an age where web applications and APIs are ubiquitous, even in chess; there still are native chess applications but they are limited to very computationally heavy tasks like analyzing positions. This is not such a task.

Comment: I write some application which do something near target (get position from image) but if there is not such application maybe I will write this :)

Answer (score 6):

This will do it. https://chessvision.ai.
There is also the Chessify app on the ios store where you can take pictures of chessboards and import the position.

Comment: I tested it works only problem that it not captures need to use Firefox in folder with images but it is good.

Comment: It chessvision.ai is good but very slow. I do not have IOS. I use Firefox with chessvision.ai.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/putz/ Lost two piece from scan

http://www.chessgrabber.nicolaas.net/        Lost one piece, added one piece, and replaced two pieces.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fimetech.chessfimee Claims to be 98% accurate.

Comment: All application is good but still not automated so you need make screenshot before.

I think that chessvision is the best on Window 10 and Chessify on phone.

Comment: I tested all that tools all are very slow on slow connection and not accurate. It is good to use but not on meeting.